# Problem with differentiation of pathparams

Tags: spring-mvc, jax-rs, resteasy

I have problem with Jax-rs @Path variable, I need to differentiate the following two pathparams

1. @Path({domain}/{id})
2. @Path({domain}/{filename})

sample url for both:
 
1. http://localhost:8080/in.com/lrth09erdfgwe 
2. http://localhost:8080/in.com/lrth09erdfgwe.xml

I think we need to use regex in pathparam! I tried it but failed to get it!
I'm using this application in Resteasy integration with spring-mvc.
Plz advice on this issue!

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

You control the matching of path parameter by putting *inside the parameter* a colon and then an RE pattern to match it, like this (where the RE is `.+[.].+`, which matches anything so long as it has at least one dot somewhere in the middle):

```
@Path("{domain}/{filename:.+[.].+}")
```

I use this in one of my services (which uses Apache CXF, but I believe this is a feature of all JAX-RS implementations). Have a care though! You can match path separators with this, which can make things very confusing. (I think you might be better to change the structure of the URIs so that there is no ambiguity, e.g., `{domain}/id/{id}` and `{domain}/files/{filename}`. I bet your clients will grok that much more rapidly.)

Comment: Also, if you're handling filenames, take a little time to ensure that you never allow `..` (or a bunch of other extra things on Windows).

Comment: Thanks for ur advice! Donal. I tried it... but it will calls the first service. I used {domain}/{filename}{param:.*}, It's working fine now!